# Pyspark dataframe to read redis data

Tags: pyspark, redis, databricks

I am unable to read Redis data in my spark dataframe. I am executing this on my databricks.

I have installed the required libraries in my cluster.

Below is the error:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark=SparkSession\
.builder\
.appName('MyApp')\
.config('spark.redis.host','')\
.config('spark.redis.port','16897')\
.config('spark.redis.auth','')\
.getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.redis").option("table", 
"school").option("key.column", "id").load()

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o631.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Failed to find data source: org.apache.spark.sql.redis. Please find packages at
http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

atorg.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedToFindDataSourceError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:557)

Can someone help here pleases?

Thanks
Narayana

Comment: When using third-party libraries, you need to add the Import statement, I don't see any import 

Example scala you need  import com.redislabs.provider.redis._

Comment: How did you install spark-redis library to Databricks? Could you share the full stack trace please? Please make sure the spark-redis jar is installed to your cluster.